# Pseudo elements overlaps input

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an `input[type=file]` with custom styling and pseudo `:before` and `:after` elements. But the pseudo elements appear to be on top of the input and when I click on the input nothing happens.

Below is the code I'm using and a [demo jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/xats5xwa/1/). How can I fix this?

```
<div class="form-group image">
        <label for="image" class="control-label">Картинка</label>
        <div class="file">
              <input type="file" accept="image/png, image/jpeg, image/gif" name="image" id="image">
        </div>
       <p>Используйте<br>JPG, PNG, GIF</p>
 </div>

.file
        overflow hidden
        position relative
        width 112px
        height 112px
        cursor pointer
        border 2px solid #fff
        box-shadow 0 0 0 1px #e8e8e8
        border-radius 5px
        background url("images/PIC-copy.png")
        &:before
            content ""
            position absolute
            top calc(50% - 30px/2)
            left calc(50% - 30px/2)
            width 30px
            height 30px
            background #39ce00
            border 1px solid #fff
            border-radius 50%
        &:after
            content "+"
            position absolute
            top 33%
            left 43.5%
            font-size 24px
            text-align center
            color #fff
        &:hover:before
            background #ff3c40
        &:hover:after
            transform rotate(45deg)
            left 44.5%

        input[type="file"]
            opacity 0
            height 100%
            cursor pointer
```

Comment: Removed gif and added jsfiddle demo to the question.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to debug without a working example. You could try setting the [z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) of the elements to achieve the correct stacking order.

Comment: Can you create a Stack Snippet or jsfiddle showing the problem? It will be easier to get an answer with an example. Also, is this happening in a specific browser?